# What would happen if a body is displaced in infinitesimal steps?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, energy, work

Suppose a body is displaced by using a very small force such that the kinetic energy of the body tends to 0 as it's velocity is 0. Moreover , since there is no change in potential energy of the system so where would the work done by the force go ? Would it be utilized to heat the body ? Assuming there is no friction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have almost got it..!

When an infinitesimal force is applied for infinitesimal time, it has done it's job doing infinitesimal work on the body.

That infinitesimal work has done it's job giving the body infinitesimal kinetic energy.

After this event, the body has gained some kinetic energy. Now there is still infinitesimal force acting on the body, which will do its job again. The only difference this time is that the body has some kinetic energy.

To conclude, the kinetic energy will keep on building up. At the end, after some considerable time, body will have some measurable kinetic energy instead of infinitesimal.